# password not being accepted for sudo user with ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am running an ansible playbook as a sudo user (forcing the sudo password) - however, I am getting a response stating that the su password is incorrect even though I can do the following on the remote server (with the same password that I tried with ansible):

```
sudo su - root
```

**error message**

```
 fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Incorrect su password"}
```

**hosts**

```
[webservers]
testserver ansible_ssh_host=ec2-52-87-166-241.compute-1.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_port=9876
```

**ansible command**

```
ansible-playbook test_playbook.yml -i hosts --ask-become-pass -vvv
```

**test_playbook**

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  remote_user: testuser
  become: yes
  become_method: su
  become_user: root
  any_errors_fatal: true

  tasks: 
  - group: 
       name: devops
       state: present
  - name: create devops user with admin privileges

    user: 
      name: devops
      comment: "Devops User"
      uid: 2001
      groups: devops
```

Any thoughts on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In '`sudo su - root`' the root privilege is gained by `sudo` rather than `su` (that is why the latter doesn't ask for the root password, since it is invoked by a process already in the role of the root user).

However, in your setup you have specified `become_method: su`, which expects root's password.

So the fix will be to change `become_method` to `sudo` (or, if you know root's password, enter that one instead of your user's password).

Answer (score 8):

`sudo su - root` is not the same thing as `become_method: su`.

`su` tries to switch to another user (by default, root) and requires you to authenticate as them (that is, enter their password).  `sudo` is similar, except that it prompts for *your* password.  To prevent this from being a security catastrophic issue, `sudo` only works for users who have been explicitly given access to it via `/etc/sudoers`.

When you use `sudo su - root`, you are saying:

1. Elevate my privileges to root via `sudo`.
2. With those elevated privileges, switch to the root user account.

Now, when you specify `become_method: su` in Ansible, you are telling Ansible to use `su` **instead of** `sudo`.  The actual command will be different, but you can think of it as running the command `su - root`.  See how that's different?

You should use `become_method: sudo` instead, or remove it entirely, as it's the default.